# typeerror: expected class openpyxl.styles.fills.fill upon opening an excel file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to open an excel that is generated by one of my company's machines. When I try to open the excel in `openpyxl`, I get this error:

```
TypeError: expected <class openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill>
```

When I save and close the excel, I can then open it in python. This is really inconvenient though because there are hundreds of these excels.

**Anyone know what's going on here?**

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: The automated export that creates the xlsx seems to take a shortcut and does not fill in all information. Excel can deal with it, fills in the blanks and stores it correctly. Is there a possibility that the export of the other machine is produced in a format that is easier to import, again? A CSV or JSON, for example?